# When desiginng a CLI is there a preference/rule of thumb for using an option or a subcommand?

Tags: command-line, conventions

For example, to install a package with `pacman` one would use:
`pacman -S <package>`
While somebody using `dnf` would type:
`dnf install <package>`
While `pacman` uses the `-S` option, `dnf` uses the subcommand `install`.

Some other examples are `nmcli` and `tar`, with `nmcli connection up <connection>` (uses subcommands) and `tar -xzvf <file>` (uses options).

What are the pros and cons of each, or is it just personal preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more technical term for what you call a "word" is "subcommand". It is quite common to design a command line interface as a command with a number of subcommands each with its own set of options. Sometimes subcommands have their own subcommands. git is one such example:

```bsh
git remote add -f -t "$BRANCH_NAME" "$REMOTE_NAME" "git://example.com/repo"
```

One reason to split a CLI into subcommands is to emphasize that it can do several different related things. `dnf` can `install` pacakges, `remove` packages, `upgrade` packages, `search` for packages,  show `info` about a package etc. All quite different actions. Many of those actions have extra knobs you can tweak and choices you can make via options.

Another reason to use subcommands is that a subcommand provides a namespace for options: `--all` in `dnf list --all` means a completely different thing from `--all` in `dnf search --all`

Yet another reason to split a big CLI into subcommands is documentation. Imagine if git did not have subcommands. The entire git manual would be one looooooooong page detailing every option that git has and the relationships between them. Also: run `git commit --help` - you'll see a help page specific to the `commit` subcommand. Also: install [tldr](https://tldr.sh/) and run `tldr git commit` - you'll get a cheat sheet that is specific to the `commit` subcommand.

One more consideration is that you should *not* use subcommands if you want to allow the modes of operation they enable to be combined. You can specify multiple options in a single command invocation, but you can only specify one subcommand.

Comment: I like the distinction in the last point; amusingly people have found ways to work around that in some cases, *e.g.* package suffixes in `apt-get install` (`-` to remove a package, `_` to purge it, etc.).